# Exclude a single file from Apache https redirect

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, redirect

I have a redirect rule in my *http.conf* file to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This works well as a blanket approach, however I'd like to **exclude** robots.txt from being redirected to https (*so it should be http://www.mysite.com/robots.txt)*
This is mostly because google refuses to grab my robots.txt over ssl (?)

I've tried a couple of different ways but so far it either 404's the file or ignores it and goes to https://www.mysite.com/robots.txt (as per the rest of the site)

I tried something along the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^robots.txt
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can do this, but it may not have the effect you want. Technically, `http://www.example.com/` and `https://www.example.com/` are different sites. Better to figure out _why_ Google won't fetch your robots.txt and fix that problem.

Comment: A fair point! I'll try and have a look in to this. Logwatch was showing `404 Not Found        /robots.txt: 3 Time(s)` which triggered my investigation.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/robots\.txt$ - [L]
# or if this is in an htaccess or <Directory>:
# RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried ...

 `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`
 `RewriteRule ^/robots\.txt$ - [L]`
 `RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

but still the same results as before, I'm afraid

Comment: @Mike Where is that configuration located?